# What is deviatoric stress?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

In recently published book on Geodynamic modelling, the auther writes following  equation (equation 4.4 in image) for describing deviatoric stress
[image: Equation 4.4 in this image] . Isn't deviatoric stress is total stress minus its normal component?

Comment: It's better to write the necessary equations here. I tried to copy all relevant information from the image to the picture. Please check for correctness & completeness.

Comment: @Martin I think equation 4.2b of image should also be written in question because it was the minus sign in that equation which led me astray.

Comment: @Martin "Please check for correctness & completeness" - Without the equation numbers (4.2b) and (4.4), the answers don't make much sense to anybody except the OP, who knows what was on the original image.

Comment: @alephzero U are right. I did not remove image containing equations. Martin did.

Comment: @alephzero: I saw this in the first question queue and didn't see the answers. Note that you could have added the equations yourself or (in this case) rolled back the edit.

Comment: I thought about how to fix the edit, but I don't think it's possible, so I rolled it back. My mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't deviatoric stress is total stress minus its normal component?

Yes, and that is precisely what it says. Note in Eq 4.2b, the stress components are *minus* the pressure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plus in 4.4 because the minus sign is already in definition of P. In fact P=-(sigma), so normal components actually are subtracted